How to store the result of the recognize_async function from MediaPipe GestureRecognizer
I'm using the MediaPipe Gesture Recognizer task to recognize hand gestures. I'm running the Gesture Recognizer task in live stream mode, which uses the recognize_async() function.
The Gesture Recognizer generates a gesture detection result object for each recognition run. How can I store the result of the recognize_async() function in a variable so I can use it in the rest of my code?
Alternatively, is it possible to run the Gesture Recognizer task in live stream mode and access the results directly? This would allow me to use the gesture information further down in my code and perform additional logic or processing on it.
Here is my code
import time
import mediapipe as mp
import cv2
from datetime import datetime


BaseOptions = mp.tasks.BaseOptions
GestureRecognizer = mp.tasks.vision.GestureRecognizer
GestureRecognizerOptions = mp.tasks.vision.GestureRecognizerOptions
GestureRecognizerResult = mp.tasks.vision.GestureRecognizerResult
VisionRunningMode = mp.tasks.vision.RunningMode


targets = {
    "Thumb_Down": 3,
    "Thumb_Up": 4,
}

last_gesture = 0


def save_gesture(result: GestureRecognizerResult, output_image: mp.Image, timestamp_ms: int):
    global last_gesture

    if result.gestures:
        gesture = result.gestures[0][0].category_name

        if gesture and gesture in targets:
            if last_gesture != gesture or last_gesture == 0:
                last_gesture = gesture
                print(gesture)


options = GestureRecognizerOptions(
    base_options=BaseOptions(model_asset_path='gesture_recognizer.task'),
    running_mode=VisionRunningMode.LIVE_STREAM,
    result_callback=save_gesture)


recognizer = GestureRecognizer.create_from_options(options)


prev_timestamp_ms = 0


def detect_gesture():

    # For webcam input:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while cap.isOpened():
        # Capture a frame from the camera
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        # Check if the frame was captured successfully
        if not ret:
            print("Failed to capture a frame")
            break

        # Get the current timestamp in milliseconds
        current_timestamp_ms = int(time.time() * 1000)

        # Check if the timestamp is monotonically increasing
        if current_timestamp_ms > prev_timestamp_ms:

            # Convert the frame received from OpenCV to a MediaPipe’s Image object.
            mp_image = mp.Image(image_format=mp.ImageFormat.SRGB, data=frame)
            recognizer.recognize_async(mp_image, current_timestamp_ms)

        # Display the captured frame
        cv2.imshow('Camera Feed', frame)

        # Press 'q' to exit the loop
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    # Release the camera and close all windows
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


detect_gesture()




